# Meteor accounts-password: get the password of logged in user

Tags: encryption, meteor, meteor-accounts, cryptojs

I am trying to **encrypt** some fields in a collection in Meteor. The encryption requires the **user's login password**. The password can be obtained when the user logs in. It is stored temporarily as a variable in Meteor. However, when user refreshes their browser, the variable lost its value even though the user is still logged in. Without the password, the encryption cannot be done correctly.

I am using **accounts-password** package to handle user login and sign-up, and I am wondering if it's possible for my app to call a function to get the user's login password whenever I want to do encryption.

If it helps to answer this question, I am using Meteor version 1.3 beta 0.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [amplify](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/amplify) package to store the password temporarily and then continue to process it. Remember to clear the password after the process is done

Comment: Thanks for the quick @Thai! I'll give that a try and let you know how it works.

Comment: BTW, do you happen to know if I can clear the password automatically when user's token is expired?

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with the token stuffs of meteor account, thus cannot help you. maybe making another question on SO ?

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who have similar questions, I ended up using [persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) package, it uses amplify as a dependency, and it has an **authenticated session variable** which will be cleared automatically when the user logs out.

Comment: The authenticated variable is really helpful for my current project. Thanks

Comment: Really glad to know that! :)